Are these two novels referred to in The Overstory real, and if so, can anyone identify them?
The Overstory is a 2018 novel by Richard Powers, in which the lives of nine characters are intertwined with each other and with those of trees. At one point, two of the characters are tree-sitting in a giant redwood as a form of protest to stop loggers from cutting it down. Bored up there, they spend time reading. The novel describes it thus:

They read two fabulous novels, one three years old and the other a hundred and twenty-three. She has trouble, as they near the end of the older story, keeping her voice under control.
"You love these people?" The stories have captivated him. He cares about what happens. But she - she's broken.
"Love? Wow. Okay. Maybe. But they're all imprisoned in a shoe box, and they have no idea. I just want to shake them and yell, Get out of yourselves, damn it! Look around! But they can't, Nicky. Everything alive is just outside their field of view."
Her face crabs up and her eyes go raw again. Crying for the blindness, even of fictional beings.

Prior to this passage, the two have been reading Shakespeare, which made me initially presume these two novels were also real books. On searching, however, I'm not so sure: the only results I found for stories where people get imprisoned in shoe boxes all link back to The Overstory itself.
I'm not clear on exactly what year the narrative is set in, but it must be fairly recent or possibly near-future. That doesn't help much as regards the 3 and 123 year ages of the novels described. It's also clear to me that it will be almost impossible to identify the one of the novels, as almost no detail is given about it at all.
Are these real books, and if so, can anyone identify either of them?

Maybe it's a metaphorical shoebox. In which case we probably don't have enough information to identify the novel.

@PeterShor I did wonder that, but the "crying for the blindness, even of fictional beings" suggested to me that it wasn't metaphorical. Hardly definitive though.
